# NestJS Microservices and Cloud deployment

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, microservices, backend, nestjs

Together with a friend i try to develop a mobile application. My friend has his hands on the Flutter-App (Frontend) and i do the backend stuff with NestJs. Our goal is a microservice architecture deployed in the cloud (GCP / Firebase).

**Current Architecture:**

- *Frontend*: a Flutter app which communicates only with the public facing API.
- *API*: is a NestJS Backend providing an GraphQL endpoint secured with JWT
- *Database* Service: All data handling is done inside a separate NestJS Microservice (see below) connected to MongoDB.
- More Services: In future i would like to add many more backend-services and connect them with each other and the API

My workspace is a [nx workspace](https://nx.dev/). So i thought it is easy for me to create multiple nestjs apps and setup for each job my own microservice. For example the before mentioned database service using the [Nest microservice functionality](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics)

On my local machine this works perfect and i love NestJS and the resulting Microservice architecture. Now i do not know how to deliver this architecture to the Cloud. In "Google Cloud terms" I imagine my API as an App Engine-instance and all the connected services as Cloud Functions.

**Problem**: And there is my dominant Problem: In NestJS a Microservice is created with an config-object like the following:

```js
//database-service: main.ts
createMicroservice(AppModule,{
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    {
        host:'127.0.0.1',
        port:4000
    }
})

//api: AppModule.ts
ClientsModule.register([
    {
        name: 'DATABASE_SERVICE',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 4000
        }
    }
])
```

As you can see the config-object is static and for service and client the same. In the cloud those config-objects would be determined by the cloud and are therefore not static. And i also could imagine that such communication via TCP between the Services would not be possible.

**So in conclusion**: 
How can i solve this configuration and cross-service-communication issue? Or is my approach wrong in general?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have much insight about the way you've (or gonna) setup your devops around GCP, but to me you should be able to solve your problem using environment variables. Let us know more about the way it's currently setup and if you've thought of this, so we can investigate further (don't hesitate to update your question with more context, i.e, code, repo etc..)

Comment: So until now i did not do any testing directly on GCP. I hade too many questions around my head. I dived now deeper inside the docs and found that App Engine seems to suit my needs. But there is still the conifguration issue. My API-Service needs to know the path to database-service. I think this will help https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables but in the end maybe something like a Pub/Sub application would be good for my usecase. I will come  up with new information after some testing.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need **Service Discovery** and here's the [pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html)

And then, using **DNS** or **Registry service** like **Consul** to query your services.

Service Discovery in [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/service-directory)

Example:

- check-list-service:4566
- auth-service:3030
- mongodb:27018

**Consul** details can be found [here](https://www.consul.io/use-cases/service-discovery-and-health-checking)